# Iterating over an AttributeSet Enumeration

Tags: java, enumeration

I have the following code:

```
    private static boolean hasTargetStyle(AttributeSet attributes) {
        final Enumeration<?> attributeNames = attributes.getAttributeNames();
        while (attributeNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            final Object attributeName = attributeNames.nextElement();
            if (attributeName.equals(MY_STYLE_NAME)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Now I would think this code would step through each of the attribute names.  But it's only giving me every other attribute name (the ones with even-numbered indices).

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Your code looks fine; The problem could possibly be with the input `AttributeSet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it has an index - a `Set` doesn't have index. And the code looks fine. Unless the `getAttributeNames()` returns a wrongly-implementation enumeration, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your code at the moment, but try using [Collections.list](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#list%28java.util.Enumeration%29)

```
private static boolean hasTargetStyle(AttributeSet attributes) {
    final List<?> attributeNames = Collections.list(attributes.getAttributeNames());

    for(Object name: attributeNames){
        if(name.equals(MY_STYLE_NAME)){
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that this is a problem with `java.util.Enumeration` (although this is just an interface and the actual implementation may have a bug). Your implementation looks good to me.

Other idea: The initial `AttributeSet` may only contain every other attribute. Try to set a breakpoint and have a look at the internals of an actual attribute set.

Answer (score 0):

The internal list I was looking at in the debugger had both names and values alternating.  So, my code is correct in a certain sense, but my intent was wrong.